# Cakephp 3.5 InnerJoin

Tags: mysql, cakephp, inner-join, cakephp-3.x

I have following situation.
i have a table "drivers_events" in this there are stored the drivers which are booked for an event.
Now I would like to do following

```
SELECT
    Driver.id,
    Driver.name 
FROM
    drivers AS Driver 
    INNER JOIN
        drivers_events AS Listing 
        ON Driver.id = Listing.driver_id 
WHERE
    Listing.event_id = 83 
ORDER BY
    Driver.name ASC;
```

If I run it as a SQL query in phpmyadmin, it works perfectly and I get the correct id and name from the table "drivers".

When I do this in my controller like this

```
$drivers = $this->Jobs->query("
    SELECT
        Driver.id,
        Driver.name 
    FROM
        drivers AS Driver 
        INNER JOIN
            drivers_events AS Event 
            ON Driver.id = Event.driver_id 
    WHERE
        Event.event_id = $activeevent 
    ORDER BY
        Driver.name ASC
");
```

then i get the complete array of jobs which created in the past.

What did i do wrong ?

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a tad offtopic, but why are you using a raw query instead of the query builder? Also note that what you are showing there is a possible SQL injection vulnerability, **never ever** insert bindable values into queries directly, especially not if it's user data!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'd love to use the Query Builder, but I'm honest and do not look that way. Since I'm quite fit in SQL, I wanted to solve it just this way.
But maybe you can give me a tip as I can implement the whole CakeLike so well in QueryBuilder. Especially since it does not come out at cake what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Event key word is reserved for SQL.
Please do not use it for table alias.
Or use such this method.

```
drivers_events AS `Event`
```

Hope to be useful.

```
$result = $this->Jobs->find()
        ->enableAutoFields(true)
        ->enableHydration(false)
        ->select([
            'id' => 'Driver.id',
            'Title' => "Driver.name"
        ])
         ->join([
            'Events' => [
                'table' => 'drivers_events',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Jobs.event_id = Events.id',

                ],
            ]
        ])
        ->join([
            'Driver' => [
                'table' => 'drivers',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Events.driver_id = Driver.id',
                ],
            ]
        ])
        ->where([
            'Events.id' => $activeevent
        ])
        ->group('Driver.id')
        ->toArray();
```

Ref: [Cakephp 3 Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)

Comment: Hi omid, thanks for your answer but this doesn't solves my problem. I will get always the complete drivers table when I do it in the controller. when i do it as sql query in phpmyadmin, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot more. I have come to the conclusion that I can read out the drivers who are assigned to an event.

in the controller it looks like this

```
 $drivers = $this->Jobs->drivers_events->find('list',
      [
      'conditions' =>
      [
           'drivers_events.event_id' => $this->request->session()->read('Event.active')
      ],
      'keyField' => 'driver_id',
      'valueField' => 'driver_id'
      ]
 );
```

In the model

```
 $this->belongsTo('drivers_events', [
      'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
 ]);
```

So now I get the right drivers for a driving job within an event.
But how do I get the name of the driver from the "Drivers" table instead the ID ?

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Drivers.id, drivers.accountname

FROM TABLE__

Join table__
Join table__

And (Brand) Totaljobs.com

Having Count <4

group By Driver.id, Drivers.Accountname

Order by (Drivers.accountname)
```